# Does GNAT Studio offer a "mode" to act as a fully self-sufficient IDE for Python development?

Tags: python, configuration, ide, ada

When I look at wikipedia, it says about **GNAT Studio**:

> GPS supports a variety of programming languages other than Ada,
> including C, JavaScript, Pascal and Python.

But when I look at the **AdaCore** site, I can't seem to find the necessary guidance to adapt GNAT Studio into a [python](/questions/tagged/python) development environment.

To answer the question, yes I am aware of **IDLE** and have used it.  I have no further comment to say about that.

Comment: Not entirely sure but there are all sort of languages in the properties of the project including python. There is a built in python console. I guess the answer is yes. How easy this is going to be ... no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible.

You can find the user manual of GNAT Studio here:

https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gps/html/gps_ug/index.html

There is also a section about supported languages:

https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gps/html/gps_ug/projects.html#supported-languages

On that page you can read, that for the languages Ada, C, C++ GNAT Studio has advanced support, but other languages can be added. There is also a link to a page where it is explained how to add languages support:

https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gps/html/gps_ug/extending.html#adding-support-for-new-languages

But you should think thoroughly if it is worth the effort. GNAT Studio is mostly produced and maintained by one company only (AdaCore). There is a risk that they decide to discontinue GNAT Studio. AdaCore over the last years shows ambitions to support also Visual Studio Code (e.g. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdaCore.ada and https://docs.adacore.com/spark2014-docs/html/ug/en/source/how_to_run_gnatprove.html#running-gnatprove-from-visual-studio-code). It may be unclear if they really see a business case for two IDEs. The Open Source community for Ada is most likely too small to take over the development of GNAT Studio in case AdaCore decides to stop the investment in it.